# Unexpected jamming of a misaligned assembly

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a small assembly with several parts misaligned. By turning the grey wheel, the grey block is to rotate about its axis (Axis 1). The problem I have is that the grey wheel can't be turned further anti-clockwise given the current position. [It seems to be jammed](https://youtu.be/ozMX3gkA3W8).

[image]
[image]
[image]

The red connecting rod can freely slide in the yellow bore, which itself can rotate with the rod in the grey bore. I'd expect the red rod to extend further and turn the yellow connector.

Does anyone know why the wheel might be jammed or how it could be modified to allow continuous rotation?

Comment: "Misaligned" means improperly or incorrectly aligned. It might be more appropriate to use a term like "offset" or "off-center" here.

Comment: @Air Oh, yes. I agree.

Comment: What am I missing here?  Look at your hardware and see where you've lost clearance and two objects are hitting each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear what is constraining the motion of the gray ring (blue in the video), but it seems to be rotating on its own axis. If so, the mechanism jams because the pin at the end of the red rod hits the end of the slot in the orange L-bracket. Regardless of the position of the yellow piece WRT the gray bar, there is a fixed maximum distance between the yellow pin and the red pin.

Comment: Yes, the grey ring rotates on its own axis indeed. Is there a way to modify it so that it allows for continuous rotation?

Comment: Well, with no clear explanation about what the mechanism is supposed to do, the most obvious thing would be to make the L-bracket (and its slot) longer.